# save the records selected by checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have some records which are being populated using an API call. 
I am modifying them and now I have to save them. At present I am saving entire records loaded on the page. But I have put a check box in front of each records and only selected records are to be saved. How can I do this in AngularJS?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
$scope.save = function () {
        var confirmMsg = "Are you sure that you want to save selected changes?";
        popup(confirmMsg, function () {
            // When "Save" button is clicked:
            $scope.tableLoading = true;
            $http.post('/Planning/SaveAllPlanningOrdersInfo',
                JSON.stringify($scope.orders),
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                }
            ).success(function (data) {
                if (data.indexOf("Error") < 0) {
                    dial.messages.information(data);
                }
                else {
                    dial.messages.error(data);
                }
                // Reload the data:
                //$scope.getOrders();

            }
            ).error(function (error) {
                reportFriendlyAjaxError(error);
            })
            //.then(do_something, showErrorDetails)
            .finally(function () {
                $scope.tableLoading = false;
            });
        });

</script>
```

In the above code $scope.orders[] has all the records but I have to get only the records which are selected in the $scope.orders[], so that I can use the same function Save() but with selected records.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a virtual `selected` field to your record and use filter by this field when saving.

```js
$scope.save = function () {
        var confirmMsg = "Are you sure that you want to save selected changes?";
        popup(confirmMsg, function () {
            // When "Save" button is clicked:
            $scope.tableLoading = true;
            $http.post('/Planning/SaveAllPlanningOrdersInfo',
                JSON.stringify($filter('filter')($scope.orders, {selected: true})),
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                }
            ).success(function (data) {
                if (data.indexOf("Error") < 0) {
                    dial.messages.information(data);
                }
                else {
                    dial.messages.error(data);
                }
                // Reload the data:
                //$scope.getOrders();

            }
            ).error(function (error) {
                reportFriendlyAjaxError(error);
            })
            //.then(do_something, showErrorDetails)
            .finally(function () {
                $scope.tableLoading = false;
            });
        });
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="order.selected"/> <span ng-bind="order.title"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this, one way is, when the checkbox changed, you can add ng-model in it, and then :

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="order.selected" />
...
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.selectedOrders = [];

...

$scope.orders.forEach(function(value, index) {

  if ($scope.orders[index]['selected'] == true) {

    vm.selectedOrders.push($scope.orders[index]);
  }
}
```